# Create XML file with R

Tags: r, xml

I need to create an file i XML-format with this format. Anyone having a best practice for this?

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contacts xmlns=http://eClub.Schemas.ImportContact>
<new>
  <member>
    <memberNumber>11252976</memberNumber>
    <labels>
     <label>Change_ZipCode</label>
    </labels>
  </member>
 </new>
</contacts> ```
````

Comment: This looks fairly simple XML. Have you tried Googling with keywords `language r xml best practices`? The very first result looks promising.

Comment: Yes, but cant figure out how to get "encoding="utf-8"?" in  the root and have a problem with that "http://eClub.Schemas.ImportContact" show up both i the head and the tail om the XML-file.